# How to check system integrity after uninstalling VirtualBox kernel extensions

Tags: disk-utility, virtualbox, kernel, kernel-extensions, sip

I recently installed VirtualBox on my Mac. Then it didn't work as I expected so I decided to uninstall it. But apparently VirtualBox installed kernel extensions. I uninstalled VirtualBox with the uninstall tool in the disk image, but when I did that, my Mac warned me that I was bypassing system security features.

I have removed VirtualBox from my computer, but now I am worried that there may be leftover changes to the kernel or to system security settings. I want to put my computer back into its original state from before I installed VirtualBox. How do I check that my kernel is in its original, out of the box state?

Thank you.